# Why my TTS does not work?

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I have the following piece of code:

```
package audiovisuales.aventuresengulpiyuri;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import util.Utilidades;

public class PaginaPrimera  extends AppCompatActivity implements OnInitListener{

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_primera);
        if (!Utilidades.verificaConexion(this)){
           Utilidades.mostrarVentanaErrorDeConexion(this);
        }
        else if(Portada.getLecturaAutomatica()){
            tts= new TextToSpeech(PaginaPrimera.this, this);
            tts.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.primeraPagina), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
```

The minimum API I have set is API 19. I have checked that it enters in the else block and it detects the text to tell, but when I execute it doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if TTS is available on the device.

First, in your `onCreate` method have this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQUEST_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}
```

Then in you `onActivityResult`, check if it is ok to use TTS.

```
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Then check if the language of the device is available.

```
if (mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.getDefault()) >= 0) {
    mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
    mTts.speak(textToBeSpoken, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

If the language is not available, you may try to install the data for that language or you may change the language.